# How can I build libdogecoin for Windows with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build libdogecoin to put together a cryptocurrency app. Since I am running primarily Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022 and developing on C++, I followed the CMake instructions listed in their GitHub page over here: https://github.com/dogecoinfoundation/libdogecoin

Here are the instructions:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

I got the following error:

```bash
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (FIND_LIBRARY):
  Could not find LIBEVENT using the following names: event, event_core,
  event_extras, event_pthreads
```

I looked then tried to build the library in debug mode and it did. Here are the commands:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

I then tried to build for release mode but it failed again with the same error I got first. I looked at the directory it tries to find and the Debug folder was there but the Release was not. I do not what to do, nor how to fix it for I do not tend to build projects like these at all from the internet. Instead, I typically just download the include folder and the .lib folders and build and call it a day.

For reference, here is exactly what I get when running the `cmake ..` command:

```bash
C:\Users\chris\Documents\libdogecoin-main\build>cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
--
--         ---( Libevent 2.1.12-stable )---
--
-- Available event backends:
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR:         C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent/build
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR: C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent/build
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR:         C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR: C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent
-- PROJECT_BINARY_DIR:       C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent/build
-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR:       C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent
-- CMAKE_MODULE_PATH:        C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent/cmake/
-- CMAKE_COMMAND:            C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
-- CMAKE_ROOT:               C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM:             Windows-10.0.22621
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:        Windows
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:     10.0.22621
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR:   AMD64
-- CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:         NO
-- CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:   FALSE
-- CMAKE_C_FLAGS:            /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:         Release
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER:         C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe (id MSVC, clang 0, GNUC 0)
-- CMAKE_AR:                 C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/lib.exe
-- CMAKE_RANLIB:             :
--
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/chris/Documents/libdogecoin-main/src/libevent/build
MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET Framework

  event_core_static.vcxproj -> C:\Users\chris\Documents\libdogecoin-main\src\libevent\build\lib\Debug\event_core.lib
  event_extra_static.vcxproj -> C:\Users\chris\Documents\libdogecoin-main\src\libevent\build\lib\Debug\event_extra.lib
  event_static.vcxproj -> C:\Users\chris\Documents\libdogecoin-main\src\libevent\build\lib\Debug\event.lib
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (FIND_LIBRARY):
  Could not find LIBEVENT using the following names: event, event_core,
  event_extras, event_pthreads


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I successfully built dogecoin core in an attempt to pass the page and get library files, but it generates .a files. I am at a loss. It is worth noting that the CMake instructions only appear in the main branch.

Comment: look at https://github.com/dogecoinfoundation/libdogecoin/blob/0.1.1-dev/CMakeLists.txt. There are several options that you can set on the commandline in your configure command with [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D). See also the line that says `FIND_LIBRARY(LIBEVENT event REQUIRED)`. It's inside a `IF(WITH_NET)` block. Do you need net functions enabled? If not, then put `-DWITH_NET=NO` in your configure command.

Comment: I have a bad feeling you might have issues related to the `RANDOM_DEVICE` option too later... the default value is `/dev/urandom` and I don't know what you can set it to on windows. And UGH they don't even use it https://github.com/dogecoinfoundation/libdogecoin/blob/1a33bb5b923fd9652cfd5bf4c14676e55b209123/src/random.c#L194 and instead hardcode [`/dev/urandom`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random), which is a UNIX thing (you're on Windows). Looks like this library is having it's own problems.

Comment: In C++, they should be using [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) but this is a C library and I don't know the standard way to do this in C. You'll probably at some point have to [raise an issue ticket with the maintainers](https://github.com/dogecoinfoundation/libdogecoin/issues/new/choose) to ask if Windows and Visual Studio are actually supported by the library. If you do, please add a link here to the issue ticket you raise for posterity.

Comment: It is a shame. I do need networking capabilities. I do not see any cryptocurrency projects that would not use networking. I will most likely give up on the project all together and take a look at Bitcoin and libbitcoin instead. I appreciate taking the time looking into this. It is not worth putting the time down on something that should not be broken to begin with.

Comment: well, I wouldn't go and say it's _broken_. It just looks to me like it wasn't built to support non-UNIX platforms. You could take a look at using something like [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) to build the project. I'm not sure if that'd work though